# Can I integerate one page in react-native and rest with Android?

Tags: react-native

Example : A **Home page** in **react-native** so that it can be customized anytime and **rest in android**.Or is there any way so that after homepage (react-native) is displayed the native android page comes in to picture?

Comment: Are you saying you want to write the home view in JavaScript using React Native, and then all other pages for Android in pure Java?

Comment: yeah can i do that ? then how ?

Comment: Yes you can. Read the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html